# setTimeout after .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

The dialog won't show up after I pressed button.

Any solutions?

```
setTimeout(function() {
$(".tile").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog(); ("Game Over" + score)
    gameRunning = false;
    $("#dialogbox").text("Your score:" + score)
}, 60000);
```

Comment: See if your console shows up some syntax error..seems like there is one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your code does is binding event handle after 60 seconds. If you want to show the dialog after 60 second on click event then do it like this.

```
$(".tile").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    ("Game Over" + score)
    gameRunning = false;
    $("#dialogbox").text("Your score:" + score)
  }, 60000);
});
```

---

If you want the same behavior in your question then you are missing closing brace and parenthesis of click handler.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".tile").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    ("Game Over" + score)
    gameRunning = false;
    $("#dialogbox").text("Your score:" + score);
  })
//^---- missing closing
}, 60000);
```